# How to create the scroll box text fields eforms

Tags: pdf

I am trying to create scroll box text fields through eforms.

But I can't create the scroll bar field to enter the text in multiple lines the PDF document

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{eforms}

% From DANTE's registration form!
\newcounter{infoLineNum}
\setcounter{infoLineNum}{0}
\newcommand{\infoInput}[2][4in]{%
  \stepcounter{infoLineNum}%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{%
    \kern 4 pt
    \raisebox{.75ex}
      {\textField[\W0\BC{}\BG{}\TU{#2}]{name\theinfoLineNum}{#1}{20bp}}%
  }
    \hrulefill
}

\begin{document}
\
\begin{tabular}{lp{4in}}
   Title                 & \infoInput{Title}\\[6pt]
   First name            & \infoInput{Firstname}\\[6pt]
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Now i am getting below output:[image: My current output]

But I need below required output:

[image]

How to create the text fields to be entered multiple lines in the PDF document.

Please advice how to achieve the required output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package `eForms` provides 7 commands that permit input by users: `\listBox`, `\comboBox`, `\pushButton`,
`\checkBox`, `\radioButton`, `\textField`, and `\sigField` (see p6 of the eForms manual). eForms does not provide a scrollbox.

Multiple lines of input in each field is enabled by adding `\Ff\FfMultiline` to the definition of `\infoInput`.

This permits multiline responses in each form field:
[image]

The complete code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{eforms}

% From DANTE's registration form!
\newcounter{infoLineNum}
\setcounter{infoLineNum}{0}
\newcommand{\infoInput}[2][4in]{%
  \stepcounter{infoLineNum}%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{%
    \kern 4 pt
    \raisebox{.75ex}
      {\textField[\Ff\FfMultiline\W0\BC{}\BG{}\TU{#2}]{name\theinfoLineNum}{#1}{20bp}}% <- added \Ff\FfMultiline
  }
    \hrulefill
}

\begin{document}
\
\begin{tabular}{lp{4in}}
   Title                 & \infoInput{Title}\\[6pt]
   First name            & \infoInput{Firstname}\\[6pt]
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your solution is working awesome and your comments of eforms is very useful for me. I hearty thank to you

Comment: You are welcome. You might also check out `\Ff\FfComb` which produces a comb - vertical lines within the field to separate each character typed. Best for single line entries.